# Different response when hitting curl command with & without single quotes

Tags: ubuntu, http, curl

I am hitting [admitAD API](https://developers.admitad.com/en/doc/api_en/methods/payments/payments-list/) using curl command.

If i below URL

> curl -L -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' -X
> GET https://api.admitad.com/payments/?limit=2&has_statement=0

I am getting response

```
 {
    "_meta": {
        "count": 21,
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "results": [{},{}]
 }
```

But if i hit this URL , Notice URL enclosed in double quote

> curl -L -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' -X
> GET "https://api.admitad.com/payments/?limit=2&has_statement=0"

I am not able to get valid response

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "count": 0,
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "results": []
}
```

I even tried this in postman , But it is also giving invalid response

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without quotes, the `&` will cause everything before it to run in the background.  Effectively making your command be:

```
curl -L -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' -X GET https://api.admitad.com/payments/?limit=2
```

Followed by executing `has_statement=0` as a separate (but valid) command.

With the quotes the `&` is escaped and the intended command is sent.  Which apparently fails when it has the `&has_statement=0` part.  This is supported by the fact it fails with postman also.

Comment: Thanks , the `&` was causing this issue. I changed my complete URL to URL+ `?limit=${data.limit}'&'offset=${data.offset}'&'has_statement=${data.hasStatement}`  with `&` enclosed with single quote `'&'`

Fixed my issue